# /usr/bin/ld: client: hidden symbol `__dso_handle'

Tags: linux, g++, shared-libraries, ld

I am trying to link with a shared lib in my C++ program.

command I used: `g++ -o client Client.cpp -L. -lprint`

Following is the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: client: hidden symbol `__dso_handle' in /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbegin.o is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

> hidden symbol `__dso_handle' in /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbegin.o is referenced by DSO

Presumably `libprint.so` is that referencing DSO. You can confirm with:

```
nm ./libprint.so | grep __dso_handle
```

If that produces a `U __dso_handle` output, your `libprint.so` was built incorrectly (most likely you used `ld -shared` to link it. Don't do that, use the compiler driver, e.g. `g++ -shared ...` instead).

Comment: I encountered the same error with my program. And the error is still there even after I did "g++ -shared" thing. I was wondering if it was because i have "-std=c++0x" which will include __dso_handle reference anyway?