# what exactly is '__dso_handle' in C++

Tags: c++, gcc

I encountered the following error when building a C++ program:

```
hidden symbol `__dso_handle' in /path-to/crtbegin.o is referenced by DSO
```

(where /path-to is a full path to the crtbegin.o)

I made sure that I have "-shared -fPIC" specified when building the source cpp files and building the .so libraries used by the program. But still got the same error.

I used "nm" and "readelf" to check the libraries, and I did see every library I built have a reference to __dso_handle. For example:

```
86: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __dso_handle
```

I have two questions:

1). what exactly caused a library (in C++) contains a reference to '_dso_handle'? Would "-std=c++0x" cause that?  Or, would '-nostartfiles' cause that?  The compiler is: i686-wrs-linux-gnu-g++ v4.6.3.

2) Since crtbegin.o has definition of '__dso_handle', why is this even a problem?  Is that only because it is "hidden symbol"?  No one should have reference to a hidden symbol?

Thanks.

Update:  resolved.  See comments #3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389479/usr-bin-ld-client-hidden-symbol-dso-handle seems (to my sleepy eyes) to ask the same question.

Comment: Copy paste the command line that's used to link whatever you're creating and show us that (+ all the output that's produced).

Comment: It seems to be related to "-nostartfiles" flag. Now I removed this flag when building the lib.  And the issue is gone.

Comment: More details:  after removing "-nostartfiles" flag,  the "__dso_handle" is built into the lib as LOCAL variable. No longer referring the GLOBAL HIDDEN one in crtbegin.o